# Can't instantiate class in different file PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm trying to instantiate a class which is located in a different file.

**File A tries to instantiate the class located in File B:**

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/assign/submission/example/classes/task/class.php');
// create the instance

$test = new testing();
```

**Here is the class in File B to be instantiated:**

```
<?php
namespace assignsubmission_example\task;


class testing extends \core\task\scheduled_task {      
public function get_name() {
    // Shown in admin screens
    return 'example';
}

public function execute() {   

    echo "hello";

}                                                                                                                               
} 
?>
```

**But I get an error message:**

> Exception - Class 'testing' not found

Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: Is the ```testing``` class in a namespace?

Comment: Yes I have this at the top of the file where the class is:
`namespace assignsubmission_example\task;`

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Please paste the code itself into the question

Comment: Sorry guys, I've edited my question to show the changes you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$test = new assignsubmission_example\task\testing();
```

The only point where you don't have to specify the namespace is if you're in the same namespace of the class you're instantiating.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! I can't mark your answer as useful as I haven't got enough reputation points :(

Comment: @Coder  Though, if it worked, you can accept the answer.

Comment: Ah yes sorry forgot about that, just done it now :) thanks again